# Date object formatting

Tags: java, date-formatting, date

I'm trying to format an input date in Java which looks like follows in the debugger.

```
result = {Date@13861} "2019-09-29"
 fastTime = 1569729600000
 cdate = {Gregorian$Date@13873} "2019-09-29T00:00:00.000-0400"
```

I need to convert it into: `2019-09-28 20:00:00.0`.

My code:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeformatter_Test = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

LocalDate tempDate = LocalDate.parse(date.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd" , Locale.US ));
```

But the line below throws a runtime error saying: Unsupported field: HourOfDay

```
String result= tempDate.format(dateTimeformatter_Test);
```

What am I missing here please?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the exact error. We should be able to copy the code and run it ourselves without getting any other errors than the one you are asking about.

Comment: `date.toString()` is a bad idea as the format not specified and could change.  It looks like you have a `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.  `LocalDate` also has no concept of time, so you'll need to provide some means to inject that (ie `LocalDate` to `LocalDateTime` :/)

Comment: I think you have the zone offset wrong, because `2019-09-29T00:00:00.000-0400` is same time as `2019-09-29 04:00:00` UTC, not `2019-09-28 20:00:00.0`, so unless you're in time zone `America/New_York` and targeting time zone `-08:00` (`America/Anchorage`), your values don't make sense.

Comment: I think that you don’t mean *parse* but *format*?! *To parse* is to convert a string to an internal form, in this case a date-time object. *To format* is the opposite conversion. Please be clear about which one of them you’re after?

Comment: Also what do you need that format for? Asking because it suspiciously looks like an SQL timestamp, and you shouldn’t pass a timestamp as a string to your SQL database. Pass an  `OffsetDateTme`, an `Instant` or a `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is lacking time zone information, but here is one way to convert `2019-09-29` into `2019-09-28 20:00:00.0`:

```
System.out.println(
        LocalDate.parse("2019-09-29")
        .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")));
```

*Output*

```
2019-09-28 20:00:00.0
```

---

Here is an entirely different way, showing the values you saw in the debugger:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

java.sql.Date result = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2019-09-29");
System.out.println("result = " + result);

long fastTime = result.getTime();
System.out.println("fastTime = " + fastTime);

System.out.println("cdate = " + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(result));

ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(fastTime).atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Anchorage"));
System.out.println("zdt = " + zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")));
```

*Output*

```
result = 2019-09-29
fastTime = 1569729600000
cdate = 2019-09-29T00:00:00.000-0400
zdt = 2019-09-28 20:00:00.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a time stamp for your SQL database: don’t give your database a time stamp as a string. Give it a proper date-time object. Since JDBC 4.2 this means:

- For an SQL `timestamp with time zone` (recommended for the vast majority of purposes) provide an `OffsetDateTime`; many drivers accept an `Instant` too.
- For an SQL `timestamp` without time zone provide a `LocalDateTime`.

So for example:

```
    java.sql.Date inputDate = getFromSomewhere();
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeForDatabase = inputDate.toLocalDate()
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(dateTimeForDatabase);

    PreparedStatement stmt = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(
            "insert into your_table(your_timestamp_col) values (?)");
    stmt.setObject(1, dateTimeForDatabase);
    int rowsInserted = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Example output from the print statement in the middle:

> 2019-09-29T00:00Z

The `Z` means UTC, so this is the same point in time as the `2019-09-28 20:00:00.0` you asked for, assuming that your JVM’s time zone is some variant of North American Eastern Time (America/Toronto or America/New_York).

The object that you see in your debugger looks very much like a `java.sql.Date` object, so I have taken this type as my starting point. The `java.sql.Date` class is poorly designed, though, in fact a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class. It is also long outdated. So if you could get a modern type instead, for example a `LocalDate`, it would be advantageous.

### What went wrong in your code?

A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day, for example 2019-09-29. You were trying to format one using the format pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`. So you are asking to include the time of day in the result, but as I said, the `LocalDate` hasn’t got a time of day, so this does not make sense. The error message that you got was actually pretty precise:

> Unsupported field: HourOfDay